# KnockoutJs computed array not calculated correctly

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

The code is as follows: EmployeeModel is the viewModel and the problem is that when I change an item's property - deletedFlag in employees (obs array), deletedItems is not updated.

How can i fix this?

```
  function Employee(data) {
    this.employeid = ko.observable(data.employeid);
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    this.isactive = ko.observable(data.isactive);
    this.deletedFlag = ko.observable(false);
}

var EmployeeModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.employees = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.deletedItems = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.employees(), function (item) {
            return item.deletedFlag == true;
        });
    }, this);
}
```

EDIT: and the following code marks one item from the array for deletion

```
self.removeEmployee = function (employee) {
        employee.deletedFlag(true);
    };
```

Comment: hope that u have applied ko bindings at the end `ko.applyBindings(new EmployeeModel());`

Comment: also post some HTML to fiddle through it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `deletedFlag` is an observable, therefore you need to retrieve its current value by invoking it as a function (you cannot compare it directly to any value):

```
self.deletedItems = ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.employees(), function (item) {
        return item.deletedFlag() == true; // <===
    });
}, this);
```

Comment: yes, you beat me with couple of minutes to the solution :) thank you very much!